# Table design for related products

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I’m new to SQL Server and I’ve been assigned to work on implementing “related products” functionality in our existing database. We have a table products that looks like this

```
ProductID int, PK
Name nvarchar(100)
Price decimal
CoverImageURL nvarchar(400)
-- couple more columns exist
```

I’m thinking about adding another column to existing database like RelatedProductID but not sure if this is good design.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your solution will work only if each product can have exactly one related product. Otherwise, if one product can have more than one related products you need a referencing table that will hold all relations between products.

Try adding a new table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.RelatedProducts
(
FirstProductId int not null,
SecondProductId int not null
)
```

So when you need all related products for some product you can retrieve these with following query.

```
SELECT SecondProductId
FROM RelatedProducts
WHERE FirstProductId = @ProductID
```

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic While I agree that showing what should be the `PRIMARY KEY` and `FOREIGN KEY` need to be added, you could just comment requesting that they update the answer.  This is the correct answer to the problem and I disagree that it deserves a downvote. The answer just needs to be expanded.  Ken, you should include in your answer the this new table has both primary/foreign keys.

Comment: @bluefeet PK and FK are such the fundamental concepts that omitting them makes the answer incorrect. If/when the poster edits his answer, I'll be happy to reverse the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what *kind* of relationship you need.

I suspect what you actually need is a "many to many" relationship, in which case you'll need an additional "junction" table:

```
CREATE TABLE ProductRelation (
    ProductID1 int REFERENCES Product (ProductID),
    ProductID2 int REFERENCES Product (ProductID),
    PRIMARY KEY (ProductID1, ProductID2)
)
```